# How can xming work with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, jogl, xming

I have an OpenGL (Java + applications) application deployed on a Linux machine. I need to start this application from a Windows machine, display and operate it on Windows.
My application shows a whole screen of 2D graphics which is constantly updated. Both machines are OpenGL capable (video cards and drivers). When not remote, the application runns ok on both the Linux and the Windows machine

I'm using ssh (putty) and an X server (xming 6.9) on the Windows. All is fine but when I display my graphics I get an "unsupported colour depth" error and nothing is displayed.

Questions:
1. Is there a way I can tweak xming to display my graphics?
2. Is there a better suited solution for my system?